# Missing Expression when selecting all columns and one more

Tags: sql, oracle

This kind of query would work perfectly in SQL Server, but it does not work in Oracle.

```
select issueno, * from SOMETABLE;
```

The error message I'm getting is:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 16

What is wrong?

Comment: Late breaking news: Oracle != MSSQL.  So what is `issueno`, is it a column on SOMETABLE?

Comment: Why would you select the same column twice? It is already included in `*`.

Comment: yep, issueno is a column in SOMETABLE
I use this way of query for a convenience only. It is useful when do analysis and want see selected fields at the beginning of the result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, when working with oracle db you need alias when you use column name along with `*`

```
select issueno, A.* from SOMETABLE A;
```

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle you have to include the table name or an alias to use the *.  Try this:

```
select issueno, SOMETABLE.*
from SOMETABLE;
```