# Wrong in select statement in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

When a test with SQL Navigator(it's work fine):

```
select userid,* from user_ ;
```

but with sql developer, it get an error: `ORA-00936: missing expression`

Please explain me why SQL Navigator can but SQL Developer can not, and explain me why what is wrong here.

This question may be similar to [sql-Missi....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604698/missing-expression-when-selecting-all-columns-and-one-more) question, but not true.

Thank for your suggestion !

Comment: Thank for all attentions, why i can not code like that ?

Comment: @ypercube thank you very much for your attentioon, please tell me why i can not select as i coded :)

Comment: I don't believe you that the query works in SQL Navigator but not in SQL Developer. The error is generated by the server and does not depend on the client being used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i'm sure with you, you can test that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
select userid, user_.* from user_
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddbd2/4)

Comment: Thank, can you tell me why i can not code like that ?