# Can not drop table with special name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table has name is `FILE`(via SQL Navigator), now I would like to drop this table(sql: `drop table FILE`), but I can not, it throw an exception: `invalid table name`.
I have to change table's name, and then i can drop it:
`alter table FILE rename to FILE_`

Please explain me why I can create but I can not drop it, thank for your suggestion :)

Comment: The documentation shows the [object naming rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements008.htm), and includes a [list of reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/ap_keywd001.htm#sthref6971). You can't create a table called `FILE` without enclosing it in double-quotes either, unless SQL Navigator is doing that behind the scenes.

Comment: @Alex Poole i think so, like my question, but anyone closed my question with no answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870278/wrong-in-select-statement-in-oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create and drop table with special name.
Just use "".

```
create table "file" (..)
drop table "file"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, i would just to know why, i should close this question.

Comment: thanks a ton. I almost got mad, cause single quotes and backticks did not work in postgreSQL. Your solution did work though!

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE "FILE";
```

Enclosing the name in double quotes makes it case-sensitive but also marks it as a delimited identifier rather than a keyword.

Comment: Thank for your answer, i would just to know why, i should close this question.

Comment: Ultimately, because the SQL standard says that to create an object with the same name as a keyword, or containing characters that are normally forbidden in names (such as spaces, slashes or dashes), you have to treat the name as a delimited identifier.  That means you surround the name with double quotes (as shown).  If the name contains a double quote, you double up the double quotes: `CREATE TABLE "He said, ""Don't do it!"""( ... );`.

Comment: Many thank to your information, i just create table by boss's command :)

Comment: Don't forget, sometimes the boss doesn't think things through or has forgotten that FILE is a keyword.  It can do no harm to check "Given that we'll have to remember to write double quotes around the table name every time we use it (`SELECT * FROM "FILE"` etc), are you sure the table name should be just `FILE` rather than some qualified name such as `DebtorFile` or `CodeFile` or ...?"  Said boss may still be determined; but at least you've tried.

Comment: Please help me in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870278/wrong-in-select-statement-in-oracle

Comment: What is there to say?  Your question has been closed as a duplicate of another, and the answer in the duplicate seems clear enough.  It is explained that Oracle is fussier than other DBMS about what you write.  The SQL standard does not allow you use an unqualified `*` when most DBMS do.  I'm a little surprised, but only a very little surprised.  (I'd often wondered why the SQL standard was fussy about it; now I know that there's at least one DBMS that likes to be fussy about it.)